# Interpretation of a limit in ergodic theory

Tags: ergodic-theory

I have prove in a exercise that for a ergodic system $(X,\mathcal{B},\mu,T)$
if we take any integrable function $f$ with $\int_X f\,d\mu \neq 0$ then 
$$\lim_{N\to \infty} \log_N \left\vert \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}f \circ T^n (x) \right\vert = 1 $$

for $\mu$-a.e $x$.

What does this result mean?

Comment: You can use the pointwise ergodic theorem.